# Java error: constructor Transaction in class Transaction cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am trying to answer the following prompt:

Write a concrete class ZeroBalance that extends the abstract class Transaction, and whose `adjustAccount` method causes the Account's balance to be set to zero. Since the `ZeroBalance` class makes no use of an amount argument, your class should have a constructor that takes only two arguments and it should override the `toString` method so as not to mention any amount.

I am pretty new to coding and I am confused on how you make a constructor that takes only two arguments.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class ZeroBalance extends Transaction
{
public ZeroBalance (String time, String date ) 
    {
        super(time, date);
    }



public boolean adjustAccount ( Account acc )
{
    acc.setBalance(0);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the Account class:

```
public class Account {
private String myName;
private double myBalance;

public Account ( String name, double balance )
{
    myName = name;
    myBalance = balance;
}

public String getName()
{
    return myName;
}

public void setName ( String name )
{
    myName = name;
}

public double getBalance()
{
    return myBalance;
}

public void setBalance( double balance )
{
    myBalance = balance;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Account holder: " + myName + "; Current balance: $" + 
    myBalance;
}
}
```

And here is the Transaction class:

```
public abstract class Transaction {
private double myAmount;
private String myTime;
private String myDate;

public Transaction ( double amount, String time, String date )
{
    myAmount = amount;
    myTime = time;
    myDate = date;
}

public double getAmount()
{
    return myAmount;
}

public String getTime ()
{
    return myTime;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return myDate;
}

public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName() + " " + myAmount + " " + myTime + " " + 
    myDate;
}

public abstract boolean adjustAccount ( Account acc );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [jb-nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) and [shahaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5235392/shahaf) mentioned, you are having issues with calling your base class constructor with missing arguments. You can solve this as follows:

```
public class ZeroBalance extends Transaction
{

private static final double ZERO_BALANCE_AMOUNT = 0.0;    

public ZeroBalance (String time, String date ) 
    {
        super(time, date,ZERO_BALANCE_AMOUNT);
    }
// ....
// ....
}
```

**However**

I would actually suggest you add another constructor to Transaction as follows:

```
public abstract class Transaction {

private static final double ZERO_AMOUNT = 0.0;

private double myAmount;
private String myTime;
private String myDate;

public Transaction ( String time, String date )
{
    myAmount = ZERO_AMOUNT;
    myTime = time;
    myDate = date;
}
```

Seems more elegant IMHO, since this allows future extenders of Transaction to also start out with a zero balance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 4 years too late, but I'm putting this down in case anyone needs to find this. Essentially, you need to make sure you override `toString` and include a `0` in `super()`.

```
public class ZeroBalance extends Transaction{
    public ZeroBalance( String time, String date ){
        super( 0, time, date );
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName() + " " + super.getTime() + " " + super.getDate();
    }
    
    public boolean adjustAccount(Account acc){
        acc.setBalance( 0 );
        return true;
    }
}
```